# Django Rest Framework session authentication default view JSON Parse

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework, axios, postman

I'm making a user session auth via DRF, React and Axios. I also use Postman for testing my endpoints. So the question is how to make default login view from rest_framework.urls work with JSON format. When I send user data (username and password) via form-data radio button inside Postman everything is working as intended. But when I use JSON format inside both Postman and Axios the DRF endpoint returns such html page:

[image]

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
    ]
}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('drf-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
]
```

My JSON data

```
{"username": "admin", "password": "admin"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default `rest_framework.urls` login view accepts form data and returns a JSON response. Does not accept JSON data. To fix this, create a custom login view, and then use the functions `authenticate` and `login` in the view. This will accept JSON data.

views.py

```
class CustomLoginView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        user=authenticate(request, username=request.data.get("username"), password=request.data.get("password"))
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return Response... # success response
        else:
            return Response .... # error response
```